Help with aura component that works in standard org but not works in partner portal
I have this custom component that displays a Visualforce page and email templates. In the org it works as it should, but in the partner portal it doesn't give me the same result. It already exists a component that is very similar in a different object that works on both sites.
Working component on both sites:


CMP:
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId,lightning:hasPageReference,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"  controller="SendEmailOppByAccount"  access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Opportunity"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="anexoId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="emailList" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="assunto" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="emailAc" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="optionsTemplate" type="List" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="optionsDocuments" type="List" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="optionsDocument" type="List" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isSuccess" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isNotVisiblePickList" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="nomeDocumento" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="msgError" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="msgValidation" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="nomeAnexo" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="emailBody" type="String" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="msgStage" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="valueDocument" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="Url" type="String"/>    
    <aura:attribute name="documentSelected" type="List" default="option1"/>
    <aura:attribute name="documentNotSent" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="documentSent" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isPendent" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isNotSentAttachment" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isSentAttachment" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isErrorValidation" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="docsList" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="multiple" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isStageName" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isOpenModal" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isLoading" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isError" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="filetype" type="List" default="['.pdf', '.txt', '.jpeg' , '.png']"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" recordId="{!v.recordId}" targetFields="{!v.record}" fields="Id,Name,EmailContato__c,OpportunityNumber__c,Account.Name,StageName" recordUpdated="{!c.handleClick}"/>
    <iframe id="VPF" name="theIframe" src= "{!v.Url}" height="700px" width= "100%"/>

    <div class="demo-only demo-only--sizing slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-size_2-of-2">
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isNotVisiblePickList}">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-destinatario"><b>Selecione o anexo para o envio do email </b></label>
                            <lightning:combobox onchange="{! c.handleChange }" name="SelecionemodeloEmail" options="{! v.optionsTemplate }" value="{! v.value }" type="List"/>
                        </div>   
                    </aura:if>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-destinatario"><b>Selecione o Modelo de Template para envio do Email </b></label>
                        <lightning:combobox onchange="{! c.handleChange }" name="SelecionemodeloEmail" options="{! v.optionsTemplate }" value="{! v.value }" type="List"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.docsList}"  var="doc">
                            <br/>
                            <div class="divCss" >
                                <label > <b>Nome: </b> {!doc.Nome}</label>
                                <button  class="buttonRemove slds-float_right" onclick="{!c.viewImage}" data-docnome="{!doc.IdAnexo}"  value="{!doc.Nome}" >
                                    <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="xx-small" iconName="utility:preview"/>
                                </button>
                                <button  class="buttonRemove slds-float_right" onclick="{!c.deleteImage}" data-docnome="{!doc.IdAnexo}" data-idAnexo="{!doc.IdAnexo}" value="{!doc.Nome}">
                                    <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="xx-small" iconName="utility:delete"/>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-assunto"><b>Assunto</b></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <input type="text" aura:id="assuntoInput" id="assuntoInput" placeholder="" required="" value="{!v.assunto}" class="slds-input input-modal"/>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label"  for="text-input-destinatario"><b>Destinatário</b></label>
                        <lightning:helptext content="Se incluir mais de um e-mail, utilizar como separador virgula"/> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <input type="text" aura:id="destinatarioInput" id="destinatarioInput" placeholder="" required="" value="{!v.emailAc}" class="slds-input input-modal"/>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-corpoemail"><b>Mensagem da Seleção</b></label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.emailBody}" placeholder="escreva alguma coisa..."/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element"></div>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <br/>
            </div>

            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.documentSent}">
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control"></div>
                </div>
            </aura:if>

            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpenModal}">
                <div class=" slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                    <lightning:button variant="brand"> <span class="slds-line-clamp_small " onclick="{! c.sendEmail }">Enviar</span></lightning:button>
                </div>
            </aura:if>

            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoading}">
                <ui:message title="Enviado email(s)" severity="info" closable="true">
                    Aguarde o processo...
                </ui:message>
            </aura:if>

            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isSuccess}">
                <div class=" slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                    <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-button_middle" onclick="{!c.reloadPage}">Realizado o envio do e-mail com sucesso</lightning:button>
                </div>
            </aura:if>

            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isError}">
                <div class=" slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                    <lightning:button variant="brand"> <span class="slds-line-clamp_small " onclick="{!c.reloadPage}">Não foi possivel enviar o e-mail</span></lightning:button>
                </div>
                <ui:message title="Informação" severity="error" closable="true">
                    {!v.msgError}
                </ui:message>
            </aura:if>

            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isErrorValidation}">
                <ui:message title="Informação" severity="error" closable="true" >
                    {!v.msgValidation}
                </ui:message>
            </aura:if>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>

JS controller:
({
    handleClick: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        let opp = cmp.get("v.record");
        console.log('init',opp.StageName)
        let urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        let url = window.location.href;
        let compare = url.split("/");
        let newUrl;
        if (compare[3] == 'lightning'){
            console.log('lightning')
            newUrl = 'https://cotacaolinkmonitoramento.secure.force.com/cotacaov2?recordId='+cmp.get("v.recordId")
        }else{
            console.log('comunidade')
            newUrl = 'https://linkmonitoramentobr.my.site.com/apex/cotacao?recordId=' + cmp.get("v.recordId")
            
        }
        
        console.log('dd');
        cmp.set('v.Url', newUrl);   
        cmp.set("v.assunto",'Cotação Comercial - Link Monitoramento')
        
        cmp.set("v.emailBody", 'Prezado (a) ,</br></br></br>Primeiramente, agradecemos à confiança em nosso time Link, estamos prontos para atendê    ({
    handleClick: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        let opp = cmp.get("v.record");
        console.log('init',opp.StageName);
        let urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        let url = window.location.href;
        let compare = url.split("/");
        let newUrl;

        if (compare[3] == 'lightning') {
            console.log('lightning');
            newUrl = 'https://cotacaolinkmonitoramento.secure.force.com/cotacaov2?recordId='+cmp.get("v.recordId");
        } else {
            console.log('comunidade');
            newUrl = 'https://linkmonitoramentobr.my.site.com/apex/cotacao?recordId=' + cmp.get("v.recordId");
            
        }
        
        console.log('dd');
        cmp.set('v.Url', newUrl);   
        cmp.set("v.assunto",'Cotação Comercial - Link Monitoramento')
        
        cmp.set("v.emailBody", 'Prezado (a) ,</br></br></br>Primeiramente, agradecemos à confiança em nosso time Link, estamos prontos para atendê-lo da melhor forma.</br></br></br>Abaixo encaminhamos um link para a proposta de acordo com sua solicitação que será aprovada eletronicamente.</br>Acesse sua proposta clicando no link abaixo:</br></br>(caso o link não abra, copie e cole em seu navegador)</br></br>http://cotacaolinkmonitoramento.force.com/cotacao?recordId='+opp.Id+'</br></br>Agradecemos a sua atenção e qualquer dúvida permanecemos a disposição.</br></br>Link Monitoramento.'); 
        let emailContato = opp.EmailContato__c;
        
        let action = cmp.get("c.getEmailTemplateList");
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            let valueReturn = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('valueReturn'+valueReturn);
            let optionArr = [];
            
            JSON.parse(valueReturn).forEach(item => {
                optionArr.push({
                    label: item.Name,
                    value: item.Id + '-' + item.Body,
                });
            });

            console.log('ee');
            console.log('optionArr:',optionArr);
            cmp.set("v.optionsTemplate", optionArr);    
            cmp.set("v.emailAc",emailContato);
            console.log('comunidadsse');

            if (opp.StageName != 'Aguardando Aprovação do Cliente') {
                cmp.set("v.isOpenModal",false);
                cmp.set("v.isErrorValidation", true);
                cmp.set("v.msgValidation",'Para enviar a cotação é necessário esteja na fase Aguardando Aprovação do Cliente.');
            }

            if (opp.CondicoesPgtoOpp__c < 1) {
                cmp.set("v.isOpenModal",false);
                cmp.set("v.isErrorValidation", true);
                cmp.set("v.msgValidation",'Antes de enviar a cotação simule as condições de pagamento clicando sobre a ação "Simular todas as condições".');
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    handleChange: function(component, event, helper) {
        let codDocument = component.get("v.value").split("-");
        let action = component.get("c.getTemplateDetails");

        action.setParams({
            'templateId':codDocument[0],
            'whoId':null,
            'whatId':component.get("v.recordId"),
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var valueReturn = response.getReturnValue();
            let body = valueReturn.body;
            component.set("v.emailBody", body);
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    sendEmail: function(component, event, helper) {
        let codDocument = component.get("v.value").substring(0,18);

        if (codDocument === '') {
            component.set("v.isLoading", false);
            component.set("v.isErrorValidation", true);
            component.set("v.isOpenModal", true);
            component.set("v.msgValidation",'Selecione o modelo de Template de Email.');

            return;
        }

        console.log('enviarEmail')
        component.set("v.isErrorValidation", false);
        component.set("v.isLoading", true);

        let listAnexo = component.get("v.docsList");
        let nomeAnexo = component.get("v.nomeAnexo");   
        let corpoUsarInput = true;
        let emailClienteInput = document.getElementById("destinatarioInput").value;
        let assuntoInput = document.getElementById("assuntoInput").value;
        let corpoEmail = component.get("v.emailBody");

        if (!emailClienteInput.includes("@") || assuntoInput === '') {
            component.set("v.isLoading", false);
            component.set("v.isErrorValidation", true);
            component.set("v.isOpenModal", true);
            component.set("v.msgValidation",'Verifique os campos para o envio de email.');

            return;
        }

        console.log('listAnexo'+listAnexo);
        let action = component.get("c.sendEmailTemplate");

        action.setParams({
            'idTemplateEmail':codDocument,
            'emailsList': emailClienteInput,
            'listAnexo': JSON.stringify(listAnexo),
            'corpoUsarInput': corpoUsarInput,
            'corpoEmail':corpoEmail,
            'assuntoInput':assuntoInput
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            console.log('valueReturnEmailEnviado',response.getReturnValue())
            var valueReturn = response.getReturnValue();

            if (valueReturn === 'sucesso') {
                component.set("v.isLoading", false);
                component.set("v.isOpenModal", false);
                component.set("v.isSuccess", true);
                
            } else {
                component.set("v.isLoading", false);
                component.set("v.isOpenModal", true);
                component.set("v.isErrorValidation", true);
                component.set("v.msgValidation",valueReturn);
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    },
    reloadPage: function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        window.location.reload();
    }
})

Working only on standard org:


If needed I can add some code adictions from the both components. I tried to be clear in my explanation.

Hi, thanks for your question. You should absolutely add code snippets here, as we can't diagnose the issue without seeing more detail. At first glance however, it looks like the file either isn't shared to the external users or you haven't got the right path to the image for the community. Please [edit] your question and add more detail.

What troubleshooting have you done so far? Is it a new VF page? Was the page added to the list of site pages?

Right. @CallumMacErlich , the only difference from this code to the other is the Visualforce Page that it displays. I mean it can be a access permission, but don't know where I can change it.

I solved my problem. Apparently this was happening due to a series of access permissions to the vf page, aura component and apex classes that the user did not have, in addition to the fact that I was using the wrong url to display the page I wanted.
